# Clear parameter values after running Jaspersoft Studio report

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

The following happens to me, suppose I have 3 parameters, when I place the first one and run the report it works, then I place the second and when I run the report it also works, the same thing happens with the third one, everything is always in the Input Parameters section, What happens is that if I then run the report but removing the second or third report it returns it empty, and for it to work again I have to hit the reset button but that clears all the parameters entered and I would have to place them again, Is there a way so that in Jaspersoft Studio (6.18.1) I don't have to press reset for the reports to work again?